# Django erroneously triggers the post_save signal on instance delete

Tags: django, signals

I'm trying to send an email notification when an Article instance is created or modified. I use signals and send_mail. Everything works great while I just create and modify articles. But, if I delete an Article, I've got a notification that it was updated! This is incorrect behavior. What can be a reason (and solution)?

## models.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# ...

class Article(TimeStampedModel):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(_('Slug'), unique_with=['year', 'month'], populate_from="title", db_index=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_('Image'),
                                    upload_to = upload_to)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', blank=True, null=True, 
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, db_index=True, related_name='articles')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    annotation = models.TextField(_('Brief annotation'), blank=True) # Brief annotation (1 paragraph)
    date = models.DateTimeField(_('Date'), default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(_('Modified'), db_index=True, auto_now=True)
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Year'), db_index=True, blank=True)
    month = models.CharField(_('Month'), db_index=True, max_length=2, blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(_('Is published'), default=False)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs): # Remove the media files of the article together with their folder
        from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
        if self.picture:
            with contextlib.suppress(FileNotFoundError):
                default_storage.delete( self.picture_thumbnail.path )
            self.picture.delete()
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH, 'news', str(self.year), str(self.month), str(self.slug))
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path) # Remove folder
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        # Потом допилить, чтобы год и месяц тоже выводился
        return self.title # There can be other ways: year, month and slugname, for example

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('news:detail', kwargs={'year': self.year, 'month': self.month, 'slug':self.slug})

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("year", "month", "slug")
        ordering = ['-date', '-modified',]

class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    text = RichTextField(_('Comment'), config_name = 'tiny')
    active = models.BooleanField(_('Visible'), default=True, db_index=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created at'), auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated at'),auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Comment by {self.author} on {self.article}'

    class Meta:
        #verbose_name_plural = _('Comments')
        #verbose_name = _('Comment')
        ordering = ['-created']

@receiver(post_save, sender=Article)
def email_on_article_change(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    # if a new officer is created, compose and send the email
    if created: # created -- это булевская переменная, чтобы отличать новые записи от изменений старых
        action = "created"
    else:
        action = "updated"
    title = instance.title if instance.title else "no title given"
    annotation = instance.annotation if instance.annotation else "no annotation given"
    author = instance.author if instance.author else 'no author assignment'

    subject = 'TITLE: {0}, ANNOTATION {1}, AUTHOR: {2}'.format(title, annotation, author)
    message = 'A New Article has been ' + action + '!\n'
    message += 'TITLE: ' + str(title) + '\n' + 'ANNOTATION: ' + str(annotation) + '\n' + 'AUTHOR: ' + str(author) + '\n'
    message += '--' * 30

    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        'mail@raptors.ru',
        ['michael_romanov@inbox.ru', 'romanov-spm@yandex.ru'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

P. S. I've read on this forum that sometimes this behavior can be caused by foreign keys. My Article model has two foreign keys, author and category. Also, there is a Comment model which has a foreign key 'article'. But I can't see how they can cause this problem and how to solve it. Please help me anybody!

Comment: Does `self.picture.delete()` count as a modification, prior to the actual deletion operation?

Comment: I checked: you are right. If I comment this row, the signal is not triggered. Thank you very much, Nigel! Now another question, how to solve the problem. Perhaps just delete the block "if self.picture ... "? I don't remember why it was necessary. Looks like on the article deletion all its folder is erased, including the main picture. What do you think?

Comment: The problem is solved. I moved the code for erasing the article media folder from the model to the post_save signal. Now everything works great!